# Send Alt-F1 and Alt-F2 keystrokes from PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, alt, keystrokes

I've set up an `Bitvise SSH server` in `Windows 7` and it works well except I can't control `FAR Manager` from `PuTTY` by sending `Alt-F1` and `Alf-F2` keystrokes. What to do?

Comment: `Alt`+something keys are usually caught by the system and not send over. There is no problem with `Fn` keys only, as I just tried. Consider trying `mc`, which should do similar thing and works fine over ssh (as it is proved by many generations).

Comment: You can do that programmatically instead

Comment: @Jakuje , latest (as for Jan 2018) `mc` (Midnight Commander) does not work for me on Putty (Kitty actually) when connecting to Windows Bitvise SSH Server.

Comment: Some applications expect `Alt` to send an ASCII escape character before the special key (such as `F1`), and (because this is not a realistic assumption) will often wait long enough for you to just press *Escape* followed by the special key.

Comment: There is chas sequences to do it but they seems to work only with english keyboard...